# Reporting an inappropriate or offensive user name

Tags: support, etiquette, moderation, display-names, profile-picture

On Stack Overflow we can raise a flag on an inappropriate comment or post. What if an user has an inappropriate user picture or name? "Inappropriate" being derogatory, rude, racially demeaning, defamatory, etc.

Is there a way to flag or report this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flag a question/answer/comment by such a user for moderator attention as "Other".

Explain you are flagging due to their name/avatar/about me section being offensive to you.

If you cannot find any post of this user, use the contact us link at the footer of each page to inform Stack Exchange staff - linking to their profile.

Comment: @Unheilig moderators can see history of display names, if they see repeated pattern they'll deal with the user. (warnings, then eventually suspension)