# How can I flag a username or profile content as offensive?

Tags: feature-request, flags, profile-page

For my immediate needs, I've already alerted a site moderator via chat. However, I was thinking this is something that should probably be built into the system somehow.

Today, I came across a user whose display name included some offensive language. Their actual activity on the site (questions/comments/etc.) is generally non-objectionable, so I'm looking for a way to flag the actual user profile instead.

It's also occurred to me that the same need could arise if the user's profile has objectionable content in their "About me" or other unrestricted text fields. However, there so far appears to not be any means for someone to flag profile contents.

Is there something I'm missing, or could this be added?

Comment: @grgarside Close, but not quite. The question does cover what I'm looking for but there isn't an authoritative answer to that part. Pretty much every answer is focused on users whose *behavior* has been flag-worthy - simple solution is to flag the behavior (e.g.: question/answer/comment) and let the moderators catch on to the pattern. However, what are we supposed to flag when a user is behaving perfectly fine but their profile or username is still offensive?

Comment: Any post by the user is fine. Use a custom flag and explain the situation. [This question is more direct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213180/reporting-an-inappropriate-or-offensive-user-name) (marked as duplicate of linked question)

Comment: Oooh, I'd love to see a five-way flag as duplicate split. That would be interesting. Too bad this is already closed.